# JAVA / Android - Ontouchstart instead of onClick

Tags: java, android, onclick, ontouch

We have an onClick function on our relativeLayout but the method triggers when we release our finger from the screen (onTouchEnd). We want our function to trigger on the moment my finger touches the screen.

```
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="click"     

public void click(View v){
    releaseItem();
}
```

Comment: You should use, OnTouch Event instead of OnClick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `View.setOnToucListener(listener)`

```
yourRelativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

            //Your stuff here
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```